# Use Date In If Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

This syntax presents an error of

> Data type conversion error

I thought I was comparing a string to a string?

```
Sub Test()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim dte As Date
Dim formatteddate As String
Set db = CurrentDb
dte = "01/01/2015 00:00:00"
formatteddate = Format(dte, "mm/dd/yyyy")
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If (CurrentDb.TableDefs(tdf).DateCreated <= formatteddate) Then
      Debug.Print tdf.DateCreated
    End If
Next
Set db = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `dte` is a Date: `Dim dte As Date`.

Comment: Is the error on this line: `If (CurrentDb.TableDefs(tdf).DateCreated <= formatteddate) Then`? What data type is `DateCreated`?

Comment: @HansUp that got it!  How would I delete the table if the parameters are met?

Comment: Lots of choices to delete a table: `CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete`; `DoCmd.DeleteObject`; execute a SQL `DROP TABLE` statement.  Try one and post a new question with problem description and error message if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I thought I was comparing a string to a string?"*

`DateCreated` returns a Date/Time value, so the comparison `DateCreated <= formatteddate` is comparing a Date/Time to a String value.

However that is not the cause of error #3421, *"Data type conversion error."*

In `CurrentDb.TableDefs(Item)`, *Item* must be the `TableDef`'s ordinal number or *Name* property.  (See the *TableDefs Collection* topic in Access' help system.)

But you're giving it *tdf*, a `TableDef` object, as *Item*.  That mismatch triggers the error.  You could avoid the error by supplying *tdf.Name* for *Item*:

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs(tdf.Name).DateCreated
```

However, since you already have *tdf*, there is no need to revisit `CurrentDb.TableDefs` ... just ask for `tdf.DateCreated` directly.

That will make the error go away, but you won't get any results when comparing `DateCreated` to the *formatteddate* String value.  The solution for that problem is to compare `tdf.DateCreated` with a Date/Time value.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim dte As Date

Set db = CurrentDb
dte = #1/1/2015#
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.DateCreated <= dte Then
        Debug.Print tdf.Name, tdf.DateCreated
    End If
Next
Set db = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
```